# Uninstall ubuntu from terminal

Tags: software-installation, do-release-upgrade

I was upgrading ubuntu 14 LTS to 18 LTS. But it went wrong. There were many broken softwares. Now I am stuck in 16 LTS but with only the terminal. So I am planning to completely uninstall this and to get a new release ubuntu 18. Can someone help how to uninstall at first?

Thanks

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 14 LTS, or 18 LTS.  Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format unless specialist (eg. Ubuntu Core 18 intended for IoT or appliance devices).  You don't need to un-install it, you install over it (and you can install over the system directories without touching user directories if you wish with the right options)

Comment: The old one was Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. During upgrade stocked with 16.04.6 LTS and only the terminal is coming. So can I install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS over the old one?

Comment: You can install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS over the old one. Installing Ubuntu 18.04 over the old one will completely overwrite the old OS.

Comment: In your case, I'd probably install using *something-else* as it allows me to select my partitions & I can decide if I format or don't (I opt no-format; but be careful this check-box is easily overlooked).  Without format it will note what packages you added to your system, then wipe system directories, install the new system, the re-add back your added packages (if found in new sources [ubuntu repositories] then ask you to reboot. It does not touch your user directories unless you tell it to format that partition; but backup first regardless (*better safe than sorry*)

Comment: @guiverc re:" then re-add back your added packages" are you telling OP to do this, or are you saying that the Ubuntu installer does this? If the latter, are you sure?

Comment: @heynnema  I meant the installer does it (something-else) IF packages are found using the new sources.list (ie. ubuntu repos for 'new' release). Yes I use it (`ubiquity`, I think `calamares` too). I word nearly always in what I'd do and thus features I use

Comment: Thank You all for your suggestions. I just take a backup and install fresh Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for an uninstall. Create a backup of your important data and then do a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install, this will overwrite your current operating system.